# Laravel - Joining 3 tables in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I'm trying to join 3 tables in Eloquent namely users, departments, and roles. 
A user can only have one department and one role.
Here's how I've defined the models:

**user model:**

```
    public function department(){
        return $this->has_one('Department', 'department_id');
    }

    public function role(){
        return $this->has_one('Role', 'role_id');
    }
}
```

**department**

```
<?php
class Department extends Eloquent 
{
    public static $key = 'department_id';
    public static $table = 'sys_departments';
    public static $timestamps = false;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongs_to('User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**role**

```
class Role extends Eloquent 
{
    public static $key = 'role_id';
    public static $table = 'sys_roles';
    public static $timestamps = false;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongs_to('User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function transaction(){
        return $this->has_many('Transaction', 'transaction_id');
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm accessing them in the controller:

```
$user = User::with(array('department', 'role'))->where('user_id', '=', 1)->first();
echo $user->department->department;
```

It's producing these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `user_id` = '1' LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `user_id` = '1' LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM `sys_departments` WHERE `department_id` IN ('1')
SELECT * FROM `sys_roles` WHERE `role_id` IN ('1')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Eloquent doesn't use joins for a multitude of reasons, mainly they add complexity. If you want to do it using one query you will need to use fluent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are confusing the relationship methods,
from the laravel docs

```
class User extends Eloquent {

 public function phone()
 {
      return $this->has_one('Phone', 'my_foreign_key');
 }
}
```

The identifier **my_foreign_key** is the name of the foreign key in the phones table and it references the user id(the owner of the relationship). so in your case

```
public function department(){
    return $this->has_one('Department', 'your_user_id');
}
```

where **your_user_id** is the field you use in your deparments table to reference the user it belongs to. and as well in the other examples you provided

currently you are setting the foreign key to reference the same table and not its owner.